# Why does the page keep refreshing itself when the button is clicked? (JavaScript & HTML)

Tags: javascript, button, page-refresh

My friend and I are trying to make a basic interest calculator. We are assuming the starting month and year are the current month and year. When we click the button, the page refreshes and all data is lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function submit() {

//gets the form from the page
var form = document.getElementById("form");

//get outputs
var interest = form.elements.interest;
var total = form.elements.total;

//inputs
var principal = parseInt(form.elements.principal.value);
var rate = parseInt(form.elements.rate.value)/100/12;
var date = new Date();
var startMonth = date.getMonth()+1;
var startYear = date.getFullYear();

var endYear = parseInt(form.elements.year.value);
var endMonth = parseInt(form.elements.month.value);

var yearElapsed = endYear - startYear;


if(startMonth > endMonth)
{
    endMonth+=12;
    endYear--;
}

var monthsElapsed = endMonth - startMonth + (yearElapsed*12);

var months = 0;

while (months < monthsElapsed)
{
    interest = (principal+interest)*(rate);
    months++;
}

interest.value = interest;
total.value = interest+principal;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form">

Principal: 
<input name="principal" type="number" value="0" />

Rate: 
<input name="rate" type="number" value="0" />

End Month: 
<select name="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

End Year: 
<input name="year" type="number" value="0" />

<button type="button" onclick="submit(); return false;">Submit</button>

<br />Interest:
<output name="interest" for="rate principal month"> 0 </output>

<br />Total due:
<output name="total" for="rate principal month"> 0 </output>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're NOT stopping the default action of that button (in this case is to submit that form). Once your `submit()` in JS is executed, browser is proceeding with form submission. As there's no `action` attribute defined on your `<form>` element, browser will simply post your data to the same URL which results in a full page refresh. After the page refresh, any data entered is lost.

You can stop the default action by passing the `event` object to your click handler like below

```
<button type="button" onclick="submit(event);">Submit</button>
```

Then in your event handler function, you can call event's `preventDefault()` method.

```
function submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I did that, but whenever I hit submit, the data in the input areas are erased and the output is not updated, although, the URL does display the data that was submitted. How do I fix this? (This is my first time implementing JS)

Comment: Looks like there's some issue with using `submit` as name for handler, I changed it to `submitHandler()` and tried and saw the test alert in my sample. Try doing the same.

Comment: That did fix the issue of the inputs being erased, but why are the output values not appearing?

Comment: The problem in your code is that you're using same variable `interest` to hold two different values. Initially you got a reference to your HTML element `<output name='interest'>` and saved it in `interest` variable, so now you've a HTML element in that variable but you're using `(principal + interest ) * rate` to calculate some numerical value, so `number * HTML element` is not a valid operation. I suggest you use a different variable like `calulatedInterest` to hold your current interest value in each month.

Comment: Here's a working [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVpoBL?editors=101) with the above changes.

Comment: I hadn't checked this site in a while before finding the same problem. It's working well and functioning as intended. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :-). If you feel my answer helped you, you can accept my answer so that this question can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 0):

1. Create attribute on `form` tag `onsubmit`,

   onsubmit="return submit();"
2. Remove button Submit and add

and at the end of your `submit` function return false

```
return false;
```

and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

add

event.preventDefault();

by the end of the button click event function

Comment: This is repeating other answers.